# AWS OpsWorks Environment what is it the "my_node" and how add it to my Custom Chef JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am running Rails Application in AWS OpsWorks Environment

I try to add the "whenever" gem to my rails app and I saw that there is "whenever Cookbook".

[whenever Cookbook](https://github.com/stephenreid/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/master/whenever)

One of requirements is: "include whenever in your node's run_list:"

```
{
  "name":"my_node",
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[whenever]"
  ]
}
```

My question: what is it the "my_node" and how add it to my Custom Chef JSON

```
{
  "deploy":
  {
    "todoapp":
    {
      "database":
      {
        "adapter": "mysql2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank, Izik.